# Realm.init() cannot resolve method init not working in Application onCreate?

Tags: android, realm

Can't call init() method on Realm. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

I have added the dependency in my build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"

    }
}
```

and applied the plugin in the build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: You probably just needed a `clean project` or a `invalidate caches / restart`

Comment: btw `Realm.getInstance(Context)` was removed in 0.83.0 if I remember correctly, so that looks like a super-old version you had cached. Maybe a `compile` dependency was still in the project from an old era.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a *lagg* at Android Studio indexes system. Try next solutions:

1. **Sync gradle files**
   [image]
2. **Invalidate IDE indexes and restart**
   [image]
3. And the last assumption - move `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0` dependency **from project build.gradle** file to **build.gradle from app** and define own `buildscript` section:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'
       }
   }
   ```

   Autogenerated build.gradle for project contains next note about this:

   > // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
   >   // in the individual module build.gradle files

Answer (score 1):

So I made it work with `Realm.init(MyApp.this)` .
I think the issue is you have the dependencies inside the build.gradle of the whole project.
This:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

When you should have it inside the build.gradle of your app:
Like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
    maven { url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
maven { url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nl.hgrams.passenger"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 900
    versionName '2.8.2'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}
```

Comment: In your case builder throw exception because of you need to call `Realm.init()` first. Look at [Controlling the lifecycle of Realm instances](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances) paragraph

Comment: Using this version, I don't need init. I have no init:
      `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.90.0"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I'll update my realm version and come back with an answer if I can

Comment: @Sergey check this pls

Comment: `Realm.init(context)` was added in Realm 2.0

Comment: Looks better. I have written similar idea at 3-th section